# Изменить модель angular из внешнего кода

Tags: angularjs, javascript

Как добавить/изменить модель ангуляра со стороннего скрипта?

К примеру вот тут http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/7820/ из `modifyTodosThere` добавить в массив элемент.

Comment: так не надо делать, но если очень хочется, то через события наверное будет правильнее всего.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это совсем не angular-way, но http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/7821/ :

```
function modifyTodosThere() {
    var el = document.querySelector('[ng-controller=TodoCtrl]');
    var scope = angular.element(el).scope();

    scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.todos.push({ text: "...", done: true });
    });
}
```